# React: UseStyles with CSS Class Name Wildcard Prefix

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I apply class name wildcard styles with UseStyles? I want to apply this CSS,  with all class names prefixes with MuiFormHelperText.

```
  const useStyles = makeStyles({
    helperText: {
      '& .MuiFormHelperText-root': {
        height: '0',
        marginTop: '0',
      },
    },
  });
```

Currently, in execution the actual css Class Name is `class="MuiFormHelperText-root-1638` in Chrome Inspector. It appends numbers at the end.

Comment: Doesn't the css wildecard way work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5110337/5506730.

Comment: Hi @gazdagergo. Trying to figure out correct syntax in react, can you write code and I can send points, thanks

Comment: Sure, but if it does not work, do not upvote it as it misleads others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  helperText: {
    '*[class^="MuiFormHelperText-root"]': {
      height: '0',
      marginTop: '0',
    },
  },
})
```

OR

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  helperText: {
    '&[class^="MuiFormHelperText-root"]': {
      height: '0',
      marginTop: '0',
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: can you try in relation to this question and update answer if possible? its not working for me,  is it working in your code base? currently not in mine,  thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37508029/adding-errortext-to-material-ui-textfield-moves-other-elements

Answer (score 0):

What about using CSS wildcards like this?

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  helperText: {
    'div[class^="MuiFormHelperText-root"]': {
      height: '0',
      marginTop: '0',
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Thanks, it may not need div, so I may remove that.  Thanks

Comment: There should be something before the brackests `[]`. If not `div` than use `*`.

Comment: If you wanna use the `&` nested selector (to refer the component itself and not a child) I think you can use this way: `&[class^="MuiFormHelperText-root"]`.

Comment: can you try in relation to this question and update answer if possible? its not working for me,  is it working in your code base? currently not in mine,  thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37508029/adding-errortext-to-material-ui-textfield-moves-other-elements