# React Material, Align Items with Flexbox having HelperText

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I align helper text with other items in a Flexbox , flex-direction horizontal?
Its currently using Box with MUI text fields and selects. The first item below is shifted upwards due to helper text. `Align-items` center currently does not fix problem.

[image]

Following question does not apply, since its not moving other elements, just not aligned. [Adding ErrorText to material-ui Textfield moves other elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37508029/adding-errortext-to-material-ui-textfield-moves-other-elements)

**Update:** When I do `align-items: stretch`, everything looks good, but now the buttons filter at the right is kind of sunk below. Is there a clean way of fixing this, without adding a margin top for the right button?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying
align-items: start;
To the Box

Comment: align items start is not working for the end box

Comment: flex-start is not really working as intended either, I also tried height 75% on the button, and it seems to align better but still looks messy